# Adding Categories Through Function

Tags: categories

I am creating a template theme for WP and am wondering if there is a way of the theme adding new categories to the db, through the functions.php upon activation of the theme.

It seems like a fairly straight forward thing to do, and can quite easily be done to post formats.

Of course its simple enough to tell the end users what categories they'll need to add once the have activated the theme, but I was wondering if that could be a step we could just miss out.

Anyways, thanks for your help, and give me a slap if there is an obvious answer :)

Matt

Comment: You are talking about the activation of both a theme and a plugin. What is the relationship?

Comment: I assumed plugin was a typo and he meant theme, maybe not though.

Comment: apologies, yeah, it was a typo... what a numpty :P

Answer (score 1):

Themes do not have an equivalent of [register_activation_hook()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) like plugins.

You may also run into issues during a review if you're hoping to be hosted on the repo.  I'm not sure how creating categories classifies exactly, but doing things like creating post types is [explicitly disallowed](http://lists.wordpress.org/pipermail/theme-reviewers/2013-March/012086.html).

That said, you can use [wp_create_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_category) in your functions.php file with a check to see if the category exists with [term_exists()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists).  Code below is untested.

```
if(!term_exists('my_category_name','category')) {
    wp_create_category('my_category_name');
}
```

Comment: 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_create_category()' I have tried it before, but I can't seem to find the solution, and a google search doesn't really help me